# Call function from exec()-initialized process

Tags: c, exec

Let's say I have the following programs:

```
//gcc a_program.c -o a_program
void foo() {
    printf("foo called\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    execvp("some_other_program", argv);
}

//gcc some_other_program.c -o some_other_program
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo();
}
```

Is there a way to call foo from the new process image that `execvp()` creates?  `dlsym()` only works on binaries loaded as dynamic libraries - according to the man page, at least - so I can't just search for the symbol in the new process, even if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When you exec a program the current process is completely replaced by the new one. Environmental factors like open file descriptors are retained, but code isn't. You can't call functions from the old process in the new one.